# Should I put XSLT files in the App_Data folder of my ASP.NET Web Application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vs-web-application-project

I have a number of XSLT files in my ASP.NET Web Application solution.  Should these go in the App_Data folder?

The [MSDN 'Project Folder Structure' article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex526337.aspx) suggests that the App_Data folder is for 'data files'.  As XSLT files are not strictly 'data files' then should they go elsewhere?

I do not want end users to be able to access the XSLT files from their browsers, so App_Data seems like an obvious location for this, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `App_Data` folder is a perfectly reasonable; however a better option may be to "embed" the XSLT into your assemblies as a resource. This way you don't have to worry about deploying more files. It also makes it harder for a client to look at your XSLT code (if this bothers you).

Comment: Thanks Andy.  As the .NET User Controls are being published out from a Content Management System I do not have any code behind files (and thus no assemblies to deploy).  Therefore I will have to deploy the XSLT files to the server.

Comment: @Jonathan: in that case you are probably best going with the `App_Data` option.